# cakePHP - how do i get the items count for a related model?

Tags: cakephp, count, model-associations

The models are: `stores` and `product`, and they are associated by:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
  'Store' => array(
    'className' => 'Store',
    'foreignKey' => 'store_id'
        ))

var $hasMany = array(
  'Product' => array(
'className' => 'Product',
'foreignKey' => 'store_id'
    ))
```

I want to get a list of all stores and the count of products they have. How should I modify the call: `$this->Store->find('all', array(<..some conditions..>))` to return that type of data?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One method is to use Cake's built-in [`counterCache`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1033/counterCache-Cache-your-count) option in your association. This is probably the most performant option, though it does require adding a field to your table.

In your `stores` table, add an `INT` field called `product_count`

In your `Product` model add the `counterCache` option to your association:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Store' => array(
    'className' => 'Store',
    'foreignKey' => 'store_id',
    'counterCache' => true
 ));
```

Whenever you add or delete `Product` records, it will automatically update the `product_count` field of the associated `Store` record, so that there is no need to alter your `find` operations.

Note that if you choose this route, you will need to manually update the `product_count` field for the initial value to be correct, as it only updates after add/delete operations.

Answer (score 3):

I believe something like the following would work, however I cannot test it from here. The `COUNT()` contents might need tweaking to work with how Cake constructs its queries.

```
$this->Store->virtualFields = array('product_count' => 'COUNT(Product.id)');
$this->Store->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array('Store.id', 'Store.product_count'),
    'group' => array('Store.id'),
));
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`find('count')`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-count).

However, this may not scale well if your looking to *pair* this data with store data (see the answer by **therealtomrose**).

I've had trouble using `find('count')` and grouping data. Unfortunately this is one of those edge cases where frameworks writing queries for you fails.

Answer (score 2):

After CakePHP 2.0 you can also add [conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#counterscope) to your count and [multiple counters per model](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-countercache).

Add any integer field to your `Store` then use this in your `Product` model:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Store' => array(
        'className' => 'Store',
        'foreignKey' => 'store_id',
        'counterCache' => array(
            'anyfield', array('Product.id >' => 0),
            'stock' => array('Product.status' => 'stock')
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple find all will fetch the data you need:

```
$Stores = $this->Store->find('all');
```

The count of products at one of the stores can be returned with the following code where '0' can be replaced with the number of the store's array index:

```
count($Stores[0]['Products']); //returns an integer
```

If you want the count of products at each store, you could consider looping over all stores thus:

```
foreach ($Stores as $Store) {
    echo count($Store['Products']);
}
```

Assumptions I am making:

1. You want the count of products at each store, not product count overall.
2. You're not too concerned with performance.  If you have more than 50,000 records or so, you might want to consider pairing this back, but it will be considerably more complicated.